# AstroPy: how to transform a SkyCoord object in the GCRS frame to the topocentric frame?

Tags: coordinates, transform, astropy

In **AstroPy** the `get_sun()` method returns the equatorial coordinates of the Sun as a `SkyCoord` object in the GCRS coordinate frame. How can I transform these coordinates into the **topocentric** frame to get topocentric **equatorial** coordinates of the Sun?

I've looked at the `transform_to()` method, but it doesnt seem to offer the topocentric frame. Somewhere in the docs I've seen this statement: "The frame classes that are built in to astropy are ICRS, FK5, FK4, FK4NoETerms, Galactic, and AltAz." Does this mean, that for the transformation to the topocentric frame I would have to define a new class as a sublass of the `BaseCoordinateFrame` class?

**EDIT:** The mathematical background can be seen e.g. here (Dieudonné's answer): https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19170/transformation-from-geocentric-coordinates-into-equatorial-coordinates

I would like to know if this is already implemented in AstroPy as a ready-to-use function?

**EDIT 2:** It looks to me that I should get the desired result, if I still keep the GCRS frame, but change the `obsgeoloc`and `obsgeovel` parameters from the default values (0,0,0) to those of my actual position. But how do I do that?

**EDIT 3:** I have managed to change at least the `obsgeoloc` but it makes no difference, I get the same equatorial coordinates, unless I do something wrong or simply misunderstand the whole thing, or maybe the difference is not obvious, because the coordinate values are given with the precision to 8 decimals? (And I still dont know which values to take for `obsgeovel`, but even if I use some arbitrary values, I get again the same coordinates.)

```
<SkyCoord (GCRS: obstime=2018-12-01T00:00:00.000, obsgeoloc=(0., 0., 0.) m, obsgeovel=(0., 0., 0.) m / s): (ra, dec, distance) in (deg, deg, AU)
    (246.72726607, -21.71360187, 0.98613747)>

<GCRS Coordinate (obstime=2018-12-01T00:00:00.000, obsgeoloc=(4659791.10339651, 1289069.45080985, 4147935.86909442) m, obsgeovel=(0., 0., 0.) m / s): (ra, dec) in deg
    (246.72726607, -21.71360187)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i've understood your question correctly then what you want are the equatorial coordinates of the Sun (i.e axes aligned with ICRS axes), but for an observer at a given origin (topocentric).

In this case, instead of using `get_sun`, which always returns coordinates with a geocentric origin, you can use `astropy.coordinates.get_body` which allows one to specify the location of the observer using an `EarthLocation` object.

```
>>> from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, get_body
>>> from astropy.time import Time
>>> location = EarthLocation.of_site('lapalma')
>>> t = Time.now()
>>> sun = get_body('sun', t, location)
<SkyCoord (GCRS: obstime=2018-12-17 11:12:59.165352, obsgeoloc=(-3111752.92801233, -4649601.13172555, 3057088.20910137) m, obsgeovel=(339.04768621, -227.31606521, -0.62038673) m / s): (ra, dec, distance) in (deg, deg, AU)
(264.76635166, -23.35141062, 0.98401329)>
>>> sun = get_body('sun', t)
<SkyCoord (GCRS: obstime=2018-12-17 11:12:59.165352, obsgeoloc=(0., 0., 0.) m, obsgeovel=(0., 0., 0.) m / s): (ra, dec, distance) in (deg, deg, AU)
(264.76514306, -23.34957481, 0.98403534)>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system) wikipedia article Topocentric is another name for the AltAz frame already implemented in Astropy.

So you can do what you want by setting up an Earth Location object and transforming to AltAz:

```
>>> from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, SkyCoord, get_sun, AltAz 
>>> from astropy.time import Time 
>>> import astropy.units as u                                                                                                                                                                                      

>>> Fort_Sumner = EarthLocation(lat=34.4900*u.deg, lon=-104.221800*u.deg, height=40*u.km)                                                                                                                          

>>> get_sun(Time("2018-12-01T00:00:00")).transform_to(AltAz(location=Fort_Sumner))                                                                                                                                 
<SkyCoord (AltAz: obstime=2018-12-01T00:00:00.000, location=(-1301.01298069, -5133.33948381, 3614.02816719) km, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt, distance) in (deg, deg, km)
(245.77428805, -3.34077928, 1.47524431e+08)>
```

Comment: The AltAz frame yields topocentric height and azimuth, but I need topocentric right ascention and declination.

Comment: I have added two edits to my question, maybe they will help somehow.

Comment: You are a little out of my field of expertise at this point, my hunch would be that you need a new frame. I will ask some more people.

Comment: Topocentric just mean from a place on the Earth's surface (as opposed to geocentric). The choice of co-ordinates is not specified/forced by it being a topocentric place; you could have topocentric (RA, Dec), (HA, Dec), (Alt,Az), (ZD,Az) - most co-ordinate pairs are possible in either topocentric or geocentric frames.